# Do triggers decreases the performance? Inserted and deleted tables?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

Suppose i am having stored procedures which performs Insert/update/delete operations on table.

Depending upon some criteria i want to perform some operations.

Should i create trigger or do the operation in stored procedure itself.

Does using the triggers decreases the performance?

Does these two tables viz **Inserted** and **deleted** exists(persistent) or are created dynamically?

If they are created dynamically does it have performance issue.

If they are persistent tables then where are they?

Also if they exixts then can i access **Inserted** and **Deleted** tables in stored procedures?

Comment: Wont the performance degrade as the inserted and deleted tables are created dynamically and the records are inserted in these tables in triggers. If we do the same thing in stored procedure these tables do not come in picture thus increasing the performance.

Answer (score 11):

Will it be less performant than doing the same thing in a stored proc. Probably not but with all performance questions the only way to really know is to test both approaches with a realistic data set (if you have a 2,000,000 record table don't test with a table with 100 records!)

That said, the choice between a trigger and another method depends entirely on the need for the action in question to happen no matter how the data is updated, deleted, or inserted. If this is a business rule that must always happen no matter what, a trigger is the  best place for it or you will eventually have data integrity problems. Data in databases is frequently changed from sources other than the GUI.

When writing a trigger though there are several things you should be aware of. First, the trigger fires once for each batch, so whether you inserted one record or 100,000 records the trigger only fires once. You cannot assume ever that only one record will be affected. Nor can you assume that it will always only be a small record set. This is why it is critical to write all triggers as if you are going to insert, update or delete a million rows. That means set-based logic and no cursors or while loops if at all possible. Do not take a stored proc written to handle one record and call it in a cursor in a trigger.

Also do not send emails from a cursor, you do not want to stop all inserts, updates, or deletes if the email server is down.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a table with a trigger will not perform as well as it would without it. Logic dictates that doing something is more expensive than doing nothing.

I think your question would be more meaningful if you asked in terms of whether it is more performant than some other approach that you haven't specified.

Ultimately, I'd select the tool that is most appropriate for the job and only worry about performance if there is a problem, not before you have even implemented a solution.

Inserted and deleted tables are available within the trigger, so calling them from stored procedures is a no-go.

Comment: You got me right i want to know "whether it is more performant than any other approach"

I want to know that if Inserted and deleted tables can only be accessed in triggers then are they created when the triggers are fired or are they permanent tables? and if they are permanent tables then why cant we access them in stored procedures

Comment: INSERTED and DELETED are temporary tables that live in memory for the duration that your trigger is executing.  Once your trigger has finished executing they are gone until something else causes the trigger to fire

Comment: Sometimes thinking about performance before getting into a solution is a good thing, there's nothing worse then going so far into a project only to realize that you have to start again - Performance is something to consider in choosing the right solution __before__ you have implemented the wrong solution

Answer (score 2):

It decreases performance on the query by definition: the query is then doing something it otherwise wasn't going to do.

The other way to look at it is this: if you were going to manually be doing whatever the trigger is doing anyway then they increase performance by saving a round trip.

Take it a step further: that advantage disappears if you use a stored procedure and you're running within one server roundtrip anyway.

So it depends on how you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Performance on what? the trigger will perform an update on the DB after the event so the user of your system won't even know it's going on.  It happens in the background.

Your question is phrased in a manner quite difficult to understand.

Comment: I think the question is referring to the presence of the inserted and deleted tables. Is there a performance hit by having those structures available. My gut says no, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If your Operation is important and must never be missed, then you have 2 choice

1. Execute your operation immediately after Update/Delete with durability
2. Delay the operation by making it loosely coupled with durability.

We also faced the same issue and our production MSSQL 2016 DB > 1TB with >500 tables and need to send changes(insert, update, delete) of few columns from 20 important tables to 3rd party. Number of business process that updates those few columns in 20 important tables were > 200 and it's a tedious task to modify them because it's a legacy application. Our existing process must work without any dependency of data sharing. Data Sharing order must be important. FIFO must be maintained

eg User Mobile No: 123-456-789, it change to 123-456-123 and again change to 123-456-456

order of sending this 123-456-789 --> 123-456-123 --> 123-456-456. Subsequent request can only be send if response of first previous request is successful.

We created 20 new tables with limited columns that we want. We compare main tables and new table (MainTable1 JOIN MainTale_LessCol1) using checksum of all columns and TimeStamp Column to Identify change.
Changes are logged in APIrequest tables and updated back in MainTale_LessCol1. Run this logic in Scheduled Job every 15 min.

Separate process will pick from APIrequest and send data to 3rd party.

We Explored

1. Triggers
2. CDC (Change Data Capture)
3. 200+ Process Changes

Since our deadlines were strict, and cumulative changes on those 20 tables were > 1000/sec and our system were already on peak capacity, our current design work.

You can try CDC share your experience